# Creating regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

**My attempt**

```
preg_match("/^logs.\d{24}.\d{24}.{4}$/", $input_line, $output_array);
If matched return \d{24} in echo
```

**String**

`logs/532523532543353444444444/532523532543353444444444.log`

Preg match peseudo-code : `logs/{24 digitals}/{same24digits}.log`

Both `\d{24}` are the same number

**Question** How to get the : If matched return \d{24} in echo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (preg_match('~^logs/(\d{24})/\1\.log$~', $input_line, $m))
   echo $m[1];
```

`\1` ia back-reference to first captured group i.e. `(\d{24})`

#### [Code Demo](http://ideone.com/AyECSR)

Comment: Ok so the $m[1] result is 893259838902389058903258/893259838902389058903258.log I just need the number 893259838902389058903258

Answer (score 2):

```
logs\/(\d{24})\/\1.log
```

see demo
http://regex101.com/r/hU0uS6/1